# Outlook not respecting dovecot folders

Tags: email, dovecot, outlook

I have set up a mail server using dovecot and postfix. I have used auto=subscribe in the mailbox creation in dovecot. My webmail client works fine with the folder configuration (spam folder is junk etc.) but outlook does not respect the folder configuration. I think it is creating its own spam folder. So now the spam messages go to the main inbox in outlook. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create junk email filter on Outlook to filter spam messages?

I think you can try it. Click Home > Junk > Junk Email Options

For more details: [Overview of the Junk Email Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-the-junk-email-filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089)

Comment: Yeah its possible but still when i sent the test spam email from the same address, it goes into the inbox of outlook